# Can't open Outlook e-mail message from Windows 7 search results

Tags: windows, email, search, outlook

When I type something into the Windows 7 search box and choose **See more results** a list of found emails and files appears (I've customised my index to include my C drive too).  So far, so good.  I can open other file types by double-clicking, but there is no right-mouse menu for Outlook files, and double-clicking doesn't do anything.

On previous computers this has worked fine.  I've been through all sorts of links on Google, but none of them has the right answer (at least for me).  I'm running Windows 7 on a 64-bit computer, but running MS Office 2010 as a 32-bit application.

Any suggestions, wonderful people at StackOverflow?

Comment: This has been put on hold as off-topic by moderators, and marked down twice.  I can't see this: it's a question specific to Outlook.  Where else could it go?  Can someone please explain to me.

Comment: As the close reason states, it has nothing to do with programming.
You'll have better luck on SuperUser! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This procedure worked in my case:

```
Control Panel -> All Control Panel Items -> Programs and Features
then click on "Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2010"
then select "Change" and click "Yes" to allow the change
then select "Repair" from the list.
```

It will require a reboot to complete the process.

Comment: Good grief, it worked!  I would never have thought that this was worth trying.  Thank you!  I'd also just compacted my PST file, but I'm sure it was repairing Office 2010 which did the trick.

Comment: Hmmm ... worked for a while, but now back to the status quo.  Don't feel like repairing Office 2010 again, so may put up with this now.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

Copy one of the email files that you found to the desktop. 
Now right click on it and click properties
You should see a change button next to the program that the file will open with. 
Click it and choose Outlook. (If its not there browse to it should be under program files or program files (x86) depending on your windows/office version. Look for a folder called Microsoft Office then there should be a folder with the office version you have ie Office15 for Microsoft Office 2013 (don't ask I dont know why they didn't just say Office2013 either????) Look for Outlook.exe and that should solve the issue.)

Comment: That is amazingly good advice, thank you, and I've +1'ed it, but sadly in my case it doesn't work as I can't copy the file in the first place.  There's no right mouse button, and the usual short-cut keys such as CTRL + C don't do anything.  For normal files found (anything other than Outlook email messages), I can open and copy the files fine, by the way.

Comment: Have you tried to open outlook select any random email and then select File==> save as. Choose your desktop and click save. The mail should be saved with a .msg extension and then you will be able to right click on the tile and it and follow the steps above.

Comment: More good advice.  I did the above - still nothing!

Comment: just to clarify by .. "Outlook files, and double-clicking doesn't do anything." I assume you mean the email files them selves?

Comment: After a Windows 7 search, I mean the files which show up in the list of returned results which correspond to Outlook messages.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and came across this article (it tells you to carry out the 'repair' steps outlined above):
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2823902

That explains it as it had worked fine for years until I installed Lync last week!

Comment: Note: This is an incompatibility between Outlook / Office 2010 and Lync 2013 that occurred for me even when Outlook 2010 was installed after Lync 2013.  The install repair recommended in the KB article worked!

Answer (score 0):

Simple fix that worked for me:
when you see the results right click and instead of open press "reply".
Once I did this the email opened!
After the open worked without pressing "reply"

Comment: Sounds a good idea, but when I right-click no short-cut menu appears!

Answer (score 0):

In my case none of those fixed worked, then I realized that some of the files were blocked (as in "This file came from another computer and might be blocked to help protect this computer").
After a few searches I found this page: [Unblocking Multiple Downloaded Files with a Single Command](http://geekswithblogs.net/wildturtle/archive/2011/11/08/all-in-a-days-work-unblocking-multiple-downloaded-files-with.aspx).
The proposed fix involves downloading the utility [Streams.exe](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/itproxpsp/thread/806f0104-1caa-4a66-b504-7a681d1ccb33/)  from Microsoft and using it to delete all the alternate streams on the selected files recursively. That solved my problem.
I'm aware that this question has been solved long time ago, but, since this is one of the top hits when searching for a solution I believe this should be here.